# UITextField custom with custom placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

i wanna make a UITextField like this:

[image]

the text currently displayed is a placeholder, i have already a class to draw the text with black stroke, the problem is how to set placeholder dynamically, and how to achieve the same borders of that image.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Can you use the `attributedPlaceholder` property of the text field?

Comment: i can use it but this won't give me the result i wish to have, i have a class called KSLabel which is a label with stroke black border on it, so i need to set this label to placeholder of textfield.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a custom placeholder, subclass `UITextField` and override the `drawPlaceholderInRect:` method.

The implementation of that method should render the custom placeholder.